# Migration from DB2 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, db2, migration

Does any one have experience on migration from DB2 to MySQL ?

Please share with me.

I tried googling, but I have not received much information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Years ago, I saw versions of MySQL available for certain operating systems. One of them had a version MySQL for IBM DB2.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/se-db2.html

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247705.pdf

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/9314480/IBM-DB2-Storage-Engine-for-MySQL--Presentation

If you install MySQL with DB2 Storage Engine, you could migrate the data you want from DB2 into MyISAM tables or InnoDB tables. Then mysqldump every MyISAM or InnoDB table to SQL Text Files.

I hope this helps !!!

UPDATE : I read the first link page. It says as of MySQL 5.1.54, that storage engine is gone. If you can get a hold of MySQL 5.1.35 - 5.1.53 for any IBM OS, you can proceed from there. At least, you can contact MySQL (eh, Oracle [I hate saying that, it just does not roll off the tongue]) and see if you can get those older binaries.

Comment: thanks Rolando, its a great suggestion, I will look into it, at this moment, I have decided to use MySQL migration toolkit to migrate the databases from ibm db2 to mysql

Comment: @50LV3R, can share how u use MySQL migration toolkit to migrate db2 database to mysql?